# (JBoss 4.2.3 GA) Role of jar-versions.xml in class loading

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

What role jar-versions.xml plays in JBoss 4.2.3 GA class loading?

Great thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jar-versions.xml` is there just for reference.

You can remove it and check that nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but do you have any official proof about it (I didn't find explicit answer from my side).

Comment: I just tried deleting it myself. Empirical proof is even more reliable than official in this case. :)